# Align paragraph text to left (not just first line)

Tags: formatting, text

The following looks wrong to me, how can I fix the alignment for the whole paragraph?

```
t = StringJoin @@ Table["abcd ", {60}];
Framed[Text[Style[t, TextAlignment -> Left]]]
```

[image]

### Update

Thanks for the two answers. I'm still confused by the spacing and alignment of the first line here:

[image: ![enter image description here]]

and (when resizing the notebook) the first line looks wrong:

[image]

Is there a better way to control this in `Cell` vs `TextCell` vs `Text`, and in a way that doesn't break when changing notebook window size or magnification?

Comment: You're `Right` example shows the space that is included since `t` ends with "... abcd ". If you do `Framed @ TextCell[StringTrim @ t, TextAlignment->Right]` the space will go away.

Comment: @CarlWoll Ah my mistake, I've updated the example

Comment: This might be a bug in [`TextCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextCell) . You can work around it by adding a [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) wrapper, e.g., ``Framed @ TextCell[Row[{Style[t, TextAlignment->Left, LineIndentMaxFraction->0]}]]`` If possible, try to control things using TextCell options. If you can't, you might need to add Row wrappers.

Answer (score 8):

Use the option [LineIndent](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineIndent.html):

[image]

```
Framed[Text[Style[t, TextAlignment -> Left, LineIndent -> 0]]]
```

[image]

or the option [`LineIndentMaxFraction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineIndentMaxFraction.html):

```
Framed[Text[Style[t, TextAlignment -> Left, LineIndentMaxFraction -> 0]]]
```

[image]

Comment: If `LineIndent -> n` shifts the first line to the left, do you agree that `LineIndent -> -n` should shift only the first line to the right?

Comment: I meant how can I indent the first line to the right?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to output something that looks like text, use [`TextCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextCell):

```
Framed @ TextCell[t]
```

[image]

Another possibility:

```
TextCell[t, CellFrame->True]
```

(* Same picture *)